# Bintray new version is not synced to JCenter

Tags: maven, gradle, bintray, jcenter

A few months ago, I uploaded version 2.0 of my JARs to Bintray, and they were approved to JCenter. All worked great.

Two days ago, I uploaded version 2.1 of my JARs to Bintray, and only 25 of the 84 JARs have been published to JCenter.

https://bintray.com/intermineorg/bio/bio-tools <-- version 2.1.0

https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/intermine/bio-tools/ <-- only version 2.0.0

25 JARs have been updated correctly, but I don't see a pattern for what worked and what didn't. They all have the same path. For the ones that failed I tried to delete them and try again, but that didn't work.

Ideas? Thanks!

EDIT: This was eventually fixed by the nice people at JFrog. They updated my paths to not include the version number.

Comment: Do you remember what was the original pattern that you included to JCenter? Maybe try to delete old files and then run the recalculate metadata.

Comment: @Royg Thanks for taking the time to reply! Deleting and trying again sounds like the best idea. Originally I uploaded the JARs and then clicked the "Link to JCenter" button on each package. JFrog then approved each for JCenter, and some worked and some did not. My worry is that I am going to upload and submit to JCenter, then have this same issue again! I don't know what I did wrong.

I was actually thinking of giving up and just submitting directly to Maven Central since it's been almost two weeks.

Comment: I would advise deleting the files under root path. I would also contact Bintray's great support and just request to have all content with the path `org/intermine/` to be automatically included to JCenter.

Comment: Thanks Royg! I did contact Bintray. They did say they were going to fix the path for me but that was 10 days ago, and I am getting a little desperate! :) I am glad you had a good experience with them. That's why I was thinking of trying to move to Maven central instead.